# my logout script is not working

Tags: php, html, css, sql

```
require_once('../class.user.php');
$user_logout = new USER();


if($user_logout->is_loggedin()!="")

{
    $user_logout->redirect('login.html');
}

if(isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout']=="true")
{
    $user_logout->doLogout();
    $user_logout->redirect('login.html');
}

?>
```

this is my logout script logout.php,its not working,can somebody assist me please. its redirecting to a blank logout.php page with no php errors.I have a class user file with all my functions and a login.html as well as login.php for backend

Comment: If not mistaken, `if($user_logout->is_loggedin()!="") {     $user_logout->redirect('login.html'); }` is wrong. It should  `if(empty($user_logout->is_loggedin())) {     $user_logout->redirect('login.html'); }` instead.

Comment: It's unclear with this info. Debug more and share where is problem exactly. And also share related functions ?

Answer (score 0):

If not mistaken,

```
if($user_logout->is_loggedin()!="") { $user_logout->redirect('login.html'); }
```

-  is wrong.

It should be

```
if(empty($user_logout->is_loggedin())) { $user_logout->redirect('login.html'); }
```

instead.

Comment: What is difference between both ?

Comment: `empty($user_logout->is_loggedin())` is eaqual to `$user_logout->is_loggedin()==""` Or `!isset($user_logout->is_loggedin())`. He used `$user_logout->is_loggedin()!=""`

Comment: `empty` is useless around function calls. Just use `!func()` for the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the if statement:

```
if($user_logout->is_loggedin()!="")
```

Should be to logout the user if he is not logged in. It would make more sense if the if statement was:

```
if(!$user_logout->is_loggedin())
```

If you want the user who is already logged in to be logged out, then you need to access logout.php from the browser as logout.php?logout=true. This will cause the code within the second if statement to run